# Submit button not working when placed within echo in the form using html and php

Tags: php, html, submit

This the image of the code. I put the submit button within the echo statement and run the file on localhost but it does not display anything

```
<?php 
    require 'connect_db.php';
    require 'tc_calendar.php';

    $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date1", true);
    $myCalendar->setIcon("images/iconCalendar.gif");
    $myCalendar->setDate(01, 03, 1960);
    $myCalendar->setYearInterval(date(Y), date(Y));
    $temo = date("Y-m-d");
    $d = strtotime("+1 month");
    $myCalendar->dateAllow($temo, date("Y-m-d", $d);
    $myCalendar->setOnChange("myChanged('test')");

    echo "<html>
    <head>
    <title>Form with calendar</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    Choose a date:";
    $myCalendar->writeScript();

    echo "<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">";
    echo "</form></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: Post code, not images. (Your double quotes those break your encapsulation. You should use an editor that either points that out with syntax highlighting or throws the error)

Answer (score 1):

#### Your button echo line breaks your string.

You have 2 options to fix this:

**1. Change the outer quotes to single quotes**

This is preferred since double quotes in PHP look for variable names. Using single quotes would make it slightly faster.

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">';
```

**2. Break out of the double quotes.**

You can use back slashes to not break out of your main string.

```
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"Submit\" value=\"Submit\">";
```

Source: [PHP-Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: @user7389747 since this is the answer could you hit the checkmark next to my answer. I'm glad it worked!